# RestEasy Authorization using ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: java-8, resteasy, wildfly-10

I have implemented RestEasy Authorization using ContainerRequestFilter .However, when i called service method my filter code is throwing NullPointerException .See below code snippet

```
 ResourceMethodInvoker methodInvoker = (ResourceMethodInvoker) requestContext.getProperty(“org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker”);
    Method method = methodInvoker.getMethod();
```

requestContext.getProperty() method return NULL.Is any configuration required to read resource annotation .Please help me to resolve this issue?

Tech Stack:
Wildfly10
java1.8
RestEasy 3.0.11Final

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Question is with respect to  get property method why requestContext.getProperty(“org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker”) method returning null